# How to delete synced photos and folder from iPhone?

Tags: iphone, windows, photos

How to delete synced photos and folder from iPhone, my OS is Windows 7 and I don't want to erase all content from setting.

I have iTunes installed on my PC.

I want to delete images and folder in my iPhone except "Camera Roll"

Comment: By connecting it to the computer that synced the photos, you simply de-select the items you wish to remove. Am I missing some aspect of your dilemma?

Comment: I have now read in twenty different places how easy this is but in my case it does not work. Have an iphone 3GS, synced a subdirectory of photos to it. Now I can not detail them on the phone. When I use itunes and uncheck them I can no longer press apply because it thinks the phone is full and wont let me sync. I don’t want to wipe out the phone because I have not had a successful sync.

Comment: I had same issue and i found solution on youtube, you have to make fake folder to delete synced photos from iPhone ... here how you do in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yRlEO1kMUmI
Hope this will help

Answer (score 3):

- Connect your device to iTunes, select it in the left navigation bar.
- In the main screen, select the Photos tab.
- Check "Sync Photos" and select only the albums you want to sync. It will remove any pics on your iPhone that are not in the folder(s) selected on your PC

Answer (score 0):

1. Launch iTunes. You must be using the same account you originally used to sync the picture folders.
2. Connect your iPhone to the computer with your USB cable.
3. Click on **"iPhone"** under **"Devices"** in the menu on the left side of the page.
4. Click on the **"Photos"** tab at the top of the page.
5. Un-check the boxes beside any folders you wish to delete.
6. Click on **"Apply"** at the bottom-right of the page. This will sync your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in iTunes or iOS. You have to select "Synch Photos" in iTunes, choose "Selected folders", and leave all folders unchecked, then synch, and choose "Remove" from the pop up dialog. For some reason, just unselecting "Sync Photos" will not delete the photos from your phone.

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]